# If, ElseIf e Else com Java 8

Tags: java, if, expressões-lambda, java-8

Gostaria de construir um método utilizando Java 8, substituindo os condicionais IF, ELSE-IF E ELSE. Para tal, construí uma sequência de código, não sei se é a ideal e gostaria de ouvir opiniões ou soluções melhores.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = " A ";
    String b = " B ";
    String c = " C ";
    String d = null;


    String teste = Optional.ofNullable(d)
            .map(String::trim)
            .orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(a)
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(b)
                            .map(String::trim)
                            .orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(c)
                                    .map(String::trim)
                                    .orElse(""))));

    System.out.println(teste);
}
```

Para fins didáticos, utilizei Strings como exemplos, MAS e se por exemplo tivéssemos o seguinte caso:
utilizássemos um método "private String retornaBusca(String regex)". Se a regex encontra algo, ela retorna a String. Se ela retornar NULL, eu chamo novamente o método com outra regex. E assim vai até acabarem as regex e retornar por padrão o valor vazio ("")

Segue exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regexA = "A";
    String regexB = "B";
    String regexC = "C";

    Pattern patternA = Pattern.compile(regexA);
    Pattern patternB = Pattern.compile(regexB);
    Pattern patternC = Pattern.compile(regexC);

    String valor = " C ";


    String teste = Optional.ofNullable(valor)
            .map(str -> retornaBusca(str, patternA))
            .orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(valor)
                    .map(str -> retornaBusca(str, patternB))
                    .orElseGet(() -> Optional.ofNullable(valor)
                            .map(str -> retornaBusca(str, patternC))
                            .orElse("")));

    System.out.println(teste);
}

private static String retornaBusca(String str, Pattern regex) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(str)
            .map(regex::matcher)
            .filter(Matcher::find)
            .map(Matcher::group)
            .map(String::trim)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: O resultado desse System.out.println(teste) será que string?

Comment: Sim. Como d é nulo, ele pegará o valor de a. Se a fosse nulo, ele pega o valor de b. E assim por diante. Se chegar no C e for nulo, ele fica com valor vazio mesmo. Mas a ideia seria substituir as Strings por métodos que retornem Strings caso encontrem a partir de uma regex ou nulo caso não encontrem.

Comment: Editei minha resposta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema é que você não está utilizando `Stream`s, apenas um monte de `Optional`s. Do jeito que você fez, o código fica amarrado ao fato de ter exatamente quatro variáveis, e não um número qualquer.

Tente assim:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;

public class TesteOptional {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = " A ";
        String b = " B ";
        String c = " C ";
        String d = null;

        String teste = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d)
                .stream()
                .map(Optional::ofNullable)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::orElseThrow)
                .map(String::trim)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse("");

        System.out.println(teste);
    }
}
```

Ou se você preferir algo mais simples e mais rápido, mas menos purista:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;

public class TesteOptional {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = " A ";
        String b = " B ";
        String c = " C ";
        String d = null;

        String teste = Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d)
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x != null)
                .map(String::trim)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse("");

        System.out.println(teste);
    }
}
```

Considerando a edição da pergunta, cheguei nisso:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TesteOptional2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern a = Pattern.compile(" A ");
        Pattern b = Pattern.compile(" B ");
        Pattern c = Pattern.compile(" C ");

        String valor = " C ";

        String teste = Arrays.asList(a, b, c)
                .stream()
                .map(p -> retornaBusca(valor, p))
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::orElseThrow)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse("");

        System.out.println(teste);
    }

    private static Optional<String> retornaBusca(String str, Pattern regex) {
        return Optional
                .ofNullable(str)
                .map(regex::matcher)
                .filter(Matcher::find)
                .map(Matcher::group)
                .map(String::trim);
    }
}
```

Observe que no exemplo acima, o parâmetro `regex` de `retornaBusca` não pode ser `null`. Não sei se entendi direito o que você quer, mas acho que é isso.

Comment: Perfeito, resolve a situação. Mas e se eu quisesse substituir as Strings por métodos que retornem Strings (que podem retornar valor ou vazio). Vou dar um exemplo mais próximo do que estou utilizando: Chamo o método "private String retornaBusca(String regex)". Se a regex encontra algo, ela retorna a String. Se ela retornar NULL, eu chamo novamente o método com outra regex. E assim vai até acabarem as regex e retornar por padrão o valor vazio (""). Se precisar de algo mais concreto eu edito a pergunta com um adendo.

Comment: @GustavoBatista Acho melhor editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Um `for` simples resolve seu problema:

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = findMatchingRegex(Arrays.asList(
        () -> testRegex(null),
        () -> testRegex(" A "),
        () -> testRegex(" B "),
        () -> testRegex(" C ")
    ));

    System.out.println(result);
  }

  public static String findMatchingRegex(List<Supplier<String>> suppliers) {
    for (Supplier<String> supplier : suppliers) {
      String value = supplier.get();
      if(value != null) {
        return value.trim();
      }
    }
    return "";
  }

  public static String testRegex(String input) {
    return input;
  }
}
```

Mas, se quiser trabalhar com `streams` (Emprestando do [@Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/374963/22247)):

```
public static String findMatchingRegex(List<Supplier<String>> suppliers) {
  return suppliers.stream()
      .map(Supplier::get)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .findFirst()
      .map(String::trim)
      .orElse("");
}
```

Comment: Legal. Só uma pergunta: pq utilizar o Supplier?

Comment: @GustavoBatista Por que desta forma os testes são _lazy_, assim como o `orElseGet` do `Optional`. Se um teste der certo, os testes seguintes não precisam ser executados.